# What is the Best Practices for Optimal Performance in Silverlight and MVVM

Tags: silverlight-4.0, mvvm, ria

I have many Normalized tables - might be more than 50... I was wondering what is the best approach for defining ViewModels - individual ViewModel for each form or making Common ViewModel for multiple Forms. Because making individual forms might increase the size of the data that needs to be downloaded and it might increase the redundancy of data on the client. i.e. using Category on each form has different set of data for each of them. and On the otherside making common viewmodel for set of Forms might increase the complexity in managing stuff.

Is there any proper article describing such aspect of Development. What is the best practices for managing overall Application so that it will offer optimal performance. (Fetching minimum Data from Server)

Thanks for your time and help.

Answer (score 0):

The amount of views & models will increase the size of your [XAP](http://debugmode.net/2011/03/05/what-is-xap-file-in-silverlight/) file, which is downloaded completely on open, this can be [compressed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6790377/is-my-xap-file-too-big-and-if-so-how-do-i-make-it-smaller). Actual performance during use is different and depends on other factors as well, try using [SilverlightSpy](http://firstfloorsoftware.com/blog/silverlight-spy-4/) to get an idea of actual browser performance. It is possible to download parts of your silverlight app as required, but this is an advanced technique.

If Messaging is your main concern, then check out [Binary Messaging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee294456.aspx).

I recommend using a new ViewModel for every view, or nested Usercontrol, then use an [event aggregator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921148%28v=pandp.20%29.aspx) for communication between models.

Answer (score 0):

Typically you'll want to create a View Model for each View.  If two Views display the same data and allow the user to perform the same actions but differ only in UI implementation then they can share a View Model but the goal is to keep your View Models cohesive.  If your View Models contain code to operate multiple views you run the risk of implementing the "God Object" anti-pattern.  If you find that your View Models all share a certain amount of common code, consider moving that code to a common base class.

Remember that two completely different View Models can manipulate the same Models.  This might be the case if two views display the same data but each allows the user to interact with it in a unique way.

I would highly recommend reading *[Pro WPF and Silverlight MVVM](http://www.apress.com/9781430231622)* by Gary Hall.  It's a great book to get started with MVVM, particularly for use with WPF and/or Silverlight.